# What does "in the know" mean?

Tags: idioms

Following are a part of introductive speech given by a moderator at a meeting in the U.S. I couldn't understand or get the nuance of the sentence. Could you explain or express in another way?

"This clus is the place when you're in the know, and tonight we have some wonderful folks."
"He will bring you  in the know about a wonderful career and important issues."

Comment: Well, it's either been misquotes (slightly) or not used idiomatically, but "in the know" simply means "informed", or "understands a lot about subject X".

Answer (score 1):

Generally "in the know" refers to a group of people who share knowledge of some secret. Each member of this group is said to be "in the know" about the secret.

So, in the second sentence you mentioned, "He will bring you in the know..." essentially means "He will inform you about...", with the added connotation that these career opportunities are secret, and you're being let into a special group of people who know about them.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation that's clear for me. So, "in the know" gives you something "privalage" by being allowed to know a secret so on?

Comment: Yep, exactly. It seems that the purpose of this speech is to make you feel like you're getting a special treatment unavailable to others.

Comment: Just a note that *"He will bring you in the know" isn't idiomatic. You can say, "He will inform you, then you'll be in the know" instead.